# React JS - How to create child component dynamically based on HoC ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm mostly a new bee in ReactJS areas. My purpose is to make an ajax call from a component and based on the response pass the response data as props to child component which I need to create dynamically based on the parent ajax call. It can be through an HoC but I'm not quite sure about it.

Structure what I was assuming for -

```
<MasterComponent> // Can be a HOC
    <ProductLayout props={data} /> // should be dynamic
</MasterComponent>
```

So, **MasterComponent** will do the ajax call and if the response having two placements data (as for an example) then it will create two **ProductLayout** child components and pass the data into it as props which grabbed from ajax response with the first and second index of response.

A sample response from ajax call:

```
{
  "placements": [
    {
      "pagemap":"pdp",
      "identifier":"list_item_1",
      "title":"You might like also",
      "items":
      [
        {
          "name":"item_name_1",
          "url":"https://www.company.com/item_name_1",
          "price":"$413"
        },
        {
          "name":"item_name_2",
          "url":"https://www.company.com/item_name_1",
          "price":"$413"
        },
        {
          "name":"item_name_3",
          "url":"https://www.company.com/item_name_1",
          "price":"$413"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "pagemap":"pdp",
      "identifier":"list_item_2",
      "title":"You might like also",
      "items":
      [
        {
          "name":"item_name_1",
          "url":"https://www.company.com/item_name_1",
          "price":"$413"
        },
        {
          "name":"item_name_2",
          "url":"https://www.company.com/item_name_1",
          "price":"$413"
        },
        {
          "name":"item_name_3",
          "url":"https://www.company.com/item_name_1",
          "price":"$413"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "pagemap":"pdp",
      "identifier":"list_item_3",
      "title":"Discover more",
      "items":
      [
        {
          "name":"item_name_1",
          "url":"https://www.company.com/item_name_1",
          "price":"$413"
        },
        {
          "name":"item_name_2",
          "url":"https://www.company.com/item_name_1",
          "price":"$413"
        },
        {
          "name":"item_name_3",
          "url":"https://www.company.com/item_name_1",
          "price":"$413"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "pagemap":"pdp",
      "identifier":"list_item_4",
      "title":"Recommendation for you",
      "items":
      [
        {
          "name":"item_name_1",
          "url":"https://www.company.com/item_name_1",
          "price":"$413"
        },
        {
          "name":"item_name_2",
          "url":"https://www.company.com/item_name_1",
          "price":"$413"
        },
        {
          "name":"item_name_3",
          "url":"https://www.company.com/item_name_1",
          "price":"$413"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You could parse your response with `JSON.parse` and then map thru `placements` like this `data.placements.map(placement => <ProductLayout product={placement} />)`

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys should do the trick in this instance. It will create the correct number of  components.

```html
Object.keys(placements).map((data) => {
  return <ProductLayout data={data} />
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You fetch data inside MasterComponent right?

So it's looking like that:

```
class MasterComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // fetch() Your API request
        // this.setState({ data: response });
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;

        if (!data.placements) return null;
        return data.placements.map((data, index) => <ProductLayout data={data} />);
    }
}
```

But also you need to make a null check cause what if placements not exists in your response